# Vertical center something, inside an IMG

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the messy code:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%;">This should be vertically centered</div>
    <img src="http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/iqpw29_main_image_.jpg" width="100%" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"; />
  <img src="http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/iqpw29_main_image_.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5as2/

as you can see, the text is almost centered vertically - but as you will shrink the width, you will see thats not 100% precise. What to fix now<

Comment: You're offsetting by 50%, but not accounting for the height of the content. This means that if, for example, you have a 100px high image and a 20px high paragraph, offsetting the paragraph by 50% would make it start at 50px and end at 70px.

Comment: and if I cant know the height of "inside" div?

Comment: Well you're going about this all wrong really. You should use CSS to set the `background` of your element to that image, rather than placing text over and `img` element.

Comment: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: its not a simple text is needed....

Answer (score 1):

A pure css solution would be to set the inside div a height, and add margin: -height/2 px for it.

Example:

```
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; height: 20px; margin-top: -10px;">This should be vertically centered</div>
```

In case you don't know the height of the div, you can use js to get it, then reposition the div.

Will be something like (jQuery, directly in answer so might have some problems, adapt it pls.):

```
   $("#idDiv").css("margin-top") = parseInt($("#idDiv").height() / 2) + "px";
```

Another solution, would be to use table-cell display, and vertical-align: middle (I personally don't like it, but may fit your needs).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/a5as2/3/

```
.use-a-stylesheet-and-classes-please { top: 50%; position: absolute; }
```

It is in the middle, even if you shrink it.

You can position the elements when shrinked by using `media queries`. And... please, don't use inline styling.

Comment: start shrinking, you will see its still not 100% centered

Comment: That's true, but that's why I said that you can use `media queries`. You can't center it like you want with pure CSS if shrinked.